# EntityDataSource query inner join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entitydatasource

I have a DB with 3 tables:

```
User{UserId,UserName}
Role{RoleId,RoleName}
User_Role{UserId,RoleId}
```

This query:

```
int userIdPassByUrl = 0;
MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext();
var query = (from role in ctx.Role
        join userRole in ctx.User_Role on role.RoleId equals userRole.RoleId
        where userRole.UserId == userIdPassByUrl
        select new { role.RoleId, role.RoleName }).Distinct();
```

I need to show the result of the above query in a Gridview with an EntityDataSource, either code or set it in the design mode.

this is my EntitydataSource:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EdsRolesByUser" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="name=myDbEntities"
        DefaultContainerName="myDbEntities" EnableFlattening="False"
        EntitySetName="Roles" EntityTypeFilter="Role"
        Select="it.[RoleId], it.[RoleName]">
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488524.aspx

Comment: Hi Raphaël the samples in the link only have selects and wheres with only one table, my real problems is to accomplish the Join and the Distinct operations with my query.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with entityDataSource, you're just asking for a working linq2entity query ? Then say what's your real problem, and what you wanna get from this query...

Comment: The query is the above and I want to show it the results in a GridView working with an EntityDataSource, but I dont know how to do it. I edit my question and show my EntityDataSource.

Comment: Ok, look at here then http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/07/linq-to-sql-part-9-using-a-custom-linq-expression-with-the-lt-asp-linqdatasource-gt-control.aspx

Comment: Hi Raphaël thank you for the link, it show how to work with a LinqDataSource. I don want to exhaust your patience, but have to ask if this samples in the link you provide wich working with LinqDataSource also can be made with a EntityDataSource and how can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it. 
Have to modified the EntityDataSource removing the EntitySetName and EntityTypeFilter
attributes, and add the CommandText like this:

```
CommandText="SELECT DISTINCT userRole.RoleId, role.RoleName FROM Role AS role
INNER JOIN User_Role as userRole
ON role.RoleId = userRole.RoleId
WHERE userRole.UserId = @UserIdPassbyUrl"
```

This link help me:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(v=vs.80).aspx