# EntityDataSource with JOIN?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entitydatasource

I am binding a GridView to the following EntityDataSource:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="sessionQuery" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=encoreEntities" DefaultContainerName="encoreEntities"
    EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="sessions" Include="user, user.person" 
    Where="it.lastactivity > @NowMinusXMins" OrderBy="it.lastactivity desc" >   
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="NowMinusXMins" Type="DateTime" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

This works fine.

I have another table called SessionHistory which has a foreign key into Session.  This table keeps track of the pages visited during the session.  I want to link the Session entity into the most recent record in SessionHistory and display the page in the GridView.

The join would be something like this:

select * from session s
where s.sessionid = (select top 1 sessionid from sessionhistory order by lastactivitydate desc)

I could do it like in this post: [EntityDataSource query inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878713/entitydatasource-query-inner-join)
however, I'm trying to preserve the EF relationships so that I can reference them in my Gridview (eg. session.user.username, session.user.person.lastname, etc.)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a real-world example in which there are **two tables** with **three navigation properties**.

**Tables**

- **lm_m_location_type** table defines a location (country, city, state, etc.)
- **lm_m_location** table contains rows for locations arranged in a parent/child hierarchy (e.g. USA -->  Florida -->  Tampa, Orlando, Miami )

**Relationships**

- **lm_m_location_type** defines zero-to-many locations
- **lm_m_location** can have zero-to-many child locations
- **lm_m_location** can have zero-or-one parent locations

**Navigation Properties** (from EntityFramework via Edit XML)

- NavigationProperty Name=**ChildLocations** Relationship=DB.fk_child_loc FromRole=lm_m_location ToRole=lm_m_location1
- NavigationProperty Name=**ParentLocation** Relationship=DB.fk_parent_loc FromRole=lm_m_location1 ToRole=lm_m_location
- NavigationProperty Name=**LocationType** Relationship=DB.fk_loc_type FromRole=lm_m_location ToRole=lm_m_location_type

**Code Example:** for accessing a location and including the parent row, child rows, and the location type row.

```
//
// code from the controller
//

public ActionResult getLocation()
{
    var lm_m_location = db.lm_m_location
        .Include("ParentLocation")
        .Include("ChildLocations")
        .Include("LocationType")
        .Where(t => t.parent_location_id == LinkDB.MvcApplication.Location.Current.id);

    return View(lm_m_location.ToList());
}

//
// code from the view that accesses each of the included tables
//
@model IEnumerable<LinkDBuilder.Models.lm_m_location>

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.description)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ParentLocation.description)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LocationType.description)

    // inside a loop of the child locations
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ChildLocations.description)

    // just to show we could drill back to the grand parent location if we wanted
    // of course we would make sure there was a value first in production code
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ParentLocation.ParentLocation.description)
```

.

Comment: Thanks DG.  I was looking for a way to do this in the .aspx file.  The issue is that I can navigate to session from sessionhistory, but not the other way around.  Once solution I found was to make the EntitySetName="sessionhistories" and navigate the other way.

Comment: I think that you answered your own question, you need to have a navigation property going each way that you need to navigate.  I'll take a look and see if I can find an example for you, and if so I'll update the answer.

Comment: I completely re-wrote the answer as I found an example that drills from location to the parent location, and location to child locations in a self referencing hierarchy relationship.  It also references another table. Hope it helps.